# How to use a html file as a source of image file in <img src=""> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, https, mixed-content

I'm trying to use an html file as a source of an image file in `<img src="">` tag to avoid mixed-content warning over https while using an http image.

**Example:**

> index.html:

`<img src="./image.html" >`

> image.html:

```js
function getBase64FromImageUrl(url) {
      var img = new Image();
    
      img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
    
      img.onload = function () {
          var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          canvas.width =this.width;
          canvas.height =this.height;
    
          var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    
          var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
          dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
          document.write(dataURL);
      };
    
      img.src = url;
    }
    getBase64FromImageUrl("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
```

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="image/png"/>


<!--
I do not want to add any child tags to the body in order to display image from this base64 data. i just want to display using the content headers.
-->
```

and I'm trying to use the image data that I dump into the html file using javascript now when I tried to open the Html file and I see a string that represents an encoded URL containing the grabbed graphical data but not the actual image as the headers are not set, even though I tried setting the content headers using meta tag in html file, nothing helped. I tried setting the content headers using .httaccess file but no use.

I know it is possible to use any server side script as the content headers that we set are sent from the server along with the response to the http request.

**example:**

> image.php

```
<?php
  header("Content-Type: image/png");
  readfile("www.example.com/img.png");
?>
```

> index.html

`<img src="./image.php" >`

I'm able to do this with php but I actually want to use html and javascript.

The main Idea is to be able to use http images over https without getting a mixed content warning.

Comment: `use a html file as a source of image` - you can't. `to avoid mixed-content warning` - you can't do that either. Preventing mixed content is a security feature. If you want to avoid it for yourself, find and 1990's browser and use that

Comment: Just check this link [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)

Comment: @JaromandaX it is possible to avoid mixed-content warning using PHP.
I have already done that. Now I'm trying to implement the same using HTML and javascript.

you can check it for yourself:
https://dukaanbabu.com/beta/api/image.php

Comment: Is it? Well you've answered your own question. Well done.

Comment: You can’t set the Content-Type HTTP header on the client side using the `meta` element, nor can you use a `meta` element to otherwise somehow change the content type of a resource. Browsers are just going to use the value of the real Content-Type HTTP header the Web server sends in the response (which I’d assume is `text/html`). Or if for some reason the Web server isn’t sending any Content-Type at all in the response, you’re still not going to be able to make browsers see it as some other content-type just by using the `meta` element.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Thanks for your response. we can always force the server to send the response in whatever Content-Type we like using .httaccess

**Example:**

`AddType 'image/png' .html`

Answer (score 1):

So you might be better off dealing with an XHR and the FileReader API, like below:

```
var b64xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    b64xhr.open( "GET", url );
    b64xhr.responseType = "blob";
    b64xhr.onload = function (){
        if (b64xhr.status===200){
            reader.readAsDataURL( b64xhr.response );
        }
        else if (b64xhr.status===404){
            // error
        }
    };
var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function () {
        console.log (reader.result );
    };
b64xhr.send();
```

This doesn't  involve any sort of hack, but does have limited compatibility